# Android crashes when back button pressed

Tags: android, debugging, crash, nullpointerexception

I have an android app which gives the user the option of loading a picture from the SD card. The problem is that, after they have clicked "load from SD" and are presented with the "open with Gallery or File manager", if they press back the App locks up.

I have this report from logcat, if anybody has any idea I would greatly appreciate it !!

```
03-25 16:13:04.915: E/AndroidRuntime(1389): java.lang.RuntimeException:
Failure delivering result
ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=0, data=null}
to activity {my.img.project/my.img.project.projActivity}:
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The app crashes in the "onActivityResult" method, I presume because it does not have a way to handle the back button ???

Comment: post more details from logcat.. there is a NullPoint exception in projActivity.java file.. please post that code... and line no. from logcat details pointing to null pointer exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to know without the code, but I would bet you don't handle the "cancel" case, when the result data is `null`. Just check that the result data is not null before trying to access it.

Comment: Spot on! Added a, if(resultCode==0) break; and now all is good!